# Circulating images in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website and I'd like to make 6 images circulate around a center image.
Here's what I've found so far:

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  height:300px;
  transform: rotateX(69deg)
}

.circle {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-45deg);
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

Found this on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/oyGsI), not my work. It's the best I've seen but it still isn't quite what I'm looking for. For one thing, the images are stretched all funny. And it doesn't work with multiple images.

I want the images all to circulate *in* a circle, like how they are positioned on [my site](//prohackr112.tk).

Comment: Check this! looks like what you want to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/FQwYJ/

Comment: Problem is, the images circulate separately and I want them all to circulate a center image in unison. Sorry this was unclear; I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to build a different animation for each image. I'm sure it can be made easier with jQuery or SCSS, but I've spelled it out:

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

#center {
 margin-top: 150px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 font-size: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 position: relative;
}

.rotate {
 position: absolute;
 top: calc(50% - 50px);
 left: calc(50% - 50px);
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

.rotate:first-of-type {
 background: red;
 transform: rotate(-30deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(30deg);
 animation: rotate-1 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate-1 {
 from { transform: rotate(-30deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(30deg) }
 to { transform: rotate(330deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-330deg) }
}

.rotate:nth-of-type(2) {
 background: orange;
 transform: rotate(30deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-30deg);
 animation: rotate-2 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate-2 {
 from { transform: rotate(30deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-30deg) }
 to { transform: rotate(390deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-390deg) }
}

.rotate:nth-of-type(3) {
 background: yellow;
 transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-90deg);
 animation: rotate-3 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate-3 {
 from { transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-90deg) }
 to { transform: rotate(450deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-450deg) }
}

.rotate:nth-of-type(4) {
 background: green;
 transform: rotate(150deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-150deg);
 animation: rotate-4 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate-4 {
 from { transform: rotate(150deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-150deg) }
 to { transform: rotate(510deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-510deg) }
}

.rotate:nth-of-type(5) {
 background: blue;
 transform: rotate(210deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-210deg);
 animation: rotate-5 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate-5 {
 from { transform: rotate(210deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-210deg) }
 to { transform: rotate(570deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-570deg) }
}

.rotate:last-of-type {
 background: indigo;
 transform: rotate(270deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-270deg);
 animation: rotate-6 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate-6 {
 from { transform: rotate(270deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-270deg) }
 to { transform: rotate(630deg) translateY(-150px) rotate(-630deg) }
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
 <span>☺</span>
 <img class="rotate" src="http://v2.trex-game.tk/favicon.png" alt="T-Rex Game" width="64" height="64">
 <img class="rotate" src="/img/code.png" alt="ProHackr112 Code" width="64" height="64&quot;">
 <img class="rotate" src="/img/donut.png" alt="Have A Donut" width="75" height="80">
 <img class="rotate" src="https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addon_icons/417/417300-64.png" alt="" width="72" height="72">
 <img class="rotate" src="https://github.com/fluidicon.png" alt="" width="63" height="63">
 <img class="rotate" src="https://rubiks.com/images/carousel/solve-it-rubiks-cube.png" alt="Rubik's Cube Experiments" width="96" height="96">
</div>
```

Keep in mind that multiple animations are not good for browser performance.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been looking all over for that solution!

Comment: Implemented at [prohackr112.tk](//prohackr112.tk).